# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')

Tags: react-native

After upgrading React Native to `0.62.2`, and installing [react-native-material-dropdown](https://github.com/noway/react-native-material-dropdown)` library, project is giving this error:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/issues/220 this might help

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I solved this by,

- Commenting `itemTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style` in
  `..\node_modules\react-native-material-dropdown\src\components\dropdown`
  file.
- And remove `Animated` in `Animated.Text.propTypes.style` in

  affix/index

  helper/index

  label/index

  of `react-native-material-textfield`.
- And added `import { Animated, Text} from 'react-native';` in each of
  above three files.

Comment: Great answer but editing files under `node_modules` is not recommended. You can't add these files to source control since files under `node_modules` should be ignored. So there is no way for other developers on the same project to get the changes. And what happens if you want to upgrade to a newer version of that package? Your changes will be overwritten. A better approach would be to fork the `react-native-material-dropdown` package and publish a new package or get the changes integrated.

Comment: I ended up creating a new package with the fix in it, and some other improvements (like typescript definitions): `react-native-material-dropdown-no-proptypes`.

Comment: after editing the node_modules remember to use patch-package to patch it permanently, else the solution will be temporary

Comment: It works, thanks ! But I personnaly need to replace `Animated.Text.propTypes.style ` by `Text.propTypes`

Comment: not works for me

Answer (score 47):

Here is another solution I've found.

1. Remove installed package `react-native-material-dropdown`

   `yarn remove react-native-material-dropdown`
2. Install new packages `react-native-material-dropdown-v2` and `react-native-paper`

   `yarn add react-native-material-dropdown-v2 react-native-paper`
3. Swap `react-native-material-dropdown` to `react-native-material-dropdown-v2` in your code

   e.g.
   `import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown'` to `import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown-v2'`

Comment: Problem with this solution is that even if it replaces the dropdown fix, does not fix the react-native-material-textfield package

Comment: This works like a charm!

Answer (score 32):

I found the same problem while using @react-navigation/drawer

I've solved it by these steps.

1. Open `node_modules` and then search for `react-native-material-textfield` open the file and go to `src` folder
2. Under `src` you will see `affix`, `helper`, `label` folder - under each folder, there is an `index.js`
3. open the `index.js` of the mentioned folders one by one (all 3 folders) and search for the text `style: Animated.Text.propTypes.style`, and replace it by `style: Text.propTypes`
4. And import text form react-native like this `import { Animated , Text} from 'react-native';`
5. And now reload the terminal, and you are good to go

Comment: After doing those changes, I am getting another issue: TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluting new TextInput({})). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have solved the problem by that way which I have mentioned. And then app is working fine on my android (thought every time I have to do this after pulling from git). I would like to suggest you to uninstall the app then consider reinstalling it.

Comment: Am I really seeing this??? if you edit any file in node_modules, when you run nmp i, won't your changes be returned back to what it was???

Comment: It's a temporary solution [@Whales_Corps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5365227/whales-corps) , if you installed node_modules again then you  have to make the same changes . I'm trying for a permanent solution of this. I will update it when I will find the way to do such.

Comment: And If you change once then if you do not reinstall with command _npm install_ or _sudo npm install_ then you can freely use this one . **npm start** have no link with the changes so app will run without any issue.

Answer (score 12):

There is an issue open on github about this problem. As mentioned in the comment, it is possible to use this option to edit node modules, or create a patch so that it is not necessary to edit the files every time you add a new library or run an npm install.

**Instruction:**

- Create patches directory in your project's root
- Copy [patch](https://gist.github.com/cryser29/97cae6770fb9b22f1b8fe63ce9a79590) to
  patches/react-native-material-textfield+0.16.1.patch
- yarn add patch-package postinstall-postinstall or npm i patch-package
- yarn patch-package or npx patch-package

Fix is already applied. Add the following to package.json to not repeat the same next time:

```
 "scripts": {
+  "postinstall": "patch-package"
 }
```

https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield/issues/249#issuecomment-625791243

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while using react-native-material-dropdown.

Fix:

- navigate to `node_modules/react-native-material-textfield/src/components`
- Open files `affix/index.js`, `helper/index.js` and `label/index.js`
- Replace `style: Animated.Text.propTypes.style` with `style: Text.propType`
- import {Text} in each of these 3 files `import { Animated ,Text} from 'react-native'`

*This should fix the issue*

react-native version: 0.64.0

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the package "react-native-easy-toast" at version 2.0.0. The weird thing was, that I couldn't find "propTypes" or "Animated" anywhere in my Code or in my libs (node-modules). I'd expect to find it somewhere in the react-native-easy-toast folder in node_modules...

Anyway, after commenting all my toasts the app started again.

I now also found a patch for this: "https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-easy-toast/issues/118" and with this and from other here mentioned `patch-package` it worked with the toasts and the patch gets automatically applied after `npm install`:)

Comment: same here! updated to `"react-native-easy-toast": "~2.3.0"` when updated to expo 46

Answer (score 1):

Just update the library they updated their library with fixes here is the link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-dropdown-v2-fixed

Answer (score 1):

I am using `react-native-material-textfield` package, and I also faced this error so I added this piece of code in my JS file right before importing:

```
import { Animated, Text } from 'react-native';
Animated.Text.propTypes = Animated.Text.propTypes || Text.propTypes;
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: answer is clear

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
I have faced the same issue while using react-native-material-dropdown.
```

**Fixed using this:**

```
navigate to node_modules/react-native-material-textfield/src/components
Open files affix/index.js, helper/index.js and label/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by using this lib

> react-native-material-dropdown-no-proptypes