# My expo app not running after upgrading to expo sdk 46

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, cross-platform

I recently received a warning from google play asking me to update my app as the privacy policy link i provided was broken. After correcting the broken link, i tried to re-upload my app to google play but it was rejected due to an issue with advertising id and analytics which one had to know i was not using ads in my app, after searching around i discovered it was an issue which was fixed in sdk 46 so i upgraded to sdk 46 but my app wont run, i even reverted my code to sdk 44 and upgraded to 45 but i faced a different issue. new apps initiated with sdk 46 worked normally but after copying my app's code, i still encountered the same error. Attached is a screenshot of my package.json dependencies. I have searched everywhere and tried everything i know and found online but to no avail.
please help

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

[image]

for the first issue, i tried [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226530/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-reactnative-animated-text-pr) [Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755476/invariant-violation-viewproptypes-has-been-removed-from-react-native-migrate-t/73135908#73135908) and various other solutions but to no avail

for the second issue, i tried ejecting in addition to other several fixes i saw online, i also used registerRootComponentb directly in my App.js and index.js for expo and bare respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this — expo doctor --fix-dependencies

Comment: I did but it says didn't find any issues with this project

Comment: I guess some of your package is using deprecated proptypes. you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702392/viewproptypes-will-be-removed-from-react-native-migrate-to-viewproptypes-export .it may help or not